# What is the internal i2c address to CAT24AA16-D

Tags: i2c, datasheet, eeprom

I am interested in using this eeprom for a project. I have used used I2C devices before and usually the datasheet gave the embedded address somewhere. For the life of me I can't seem to find it on their datasheet.

Anyone want to show me where the heck it is? I feel quite silly as I even tried CTRL+F to find keywords on the datasheet.

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT24AA16-D.PDF

Comment: See "Device Addressing" on page 4. a8 to a10 select one of 8 256-byte pages in the device. See figure 6 p.6 for the rest of the story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That EEPROM has a size of 2048 bytes, which requires 11 bits to address.
The datasheet states:

[image: Device addressing]

Thus, it says the four most significant bits of the device/slave address byte are "1010", and the next 3 bits are the 3 most significant bits of the *memory address* to be accessed, with the 8 least significant bits of the memory address to access in the next byte, as clarified here:

[image: Addressing sequence]

So, for example, if you want to access memory address 1365, 10101010101 in binary, the slave address byte would be *1010*101X and the address byte would be 01010101. (Where X is the read/write bit).

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. Didn't realize the address is for each memory address. Thanks!